# Morphia saving regular expression in the database?

Tags: java, regex, mongodb, morphia

Having a problem executing a regular expression that I am storing in Mongo (2.6) using Morphia (via PlayFramework 1.2.7)

Essentially I have a model (below and snipped) that contains a string field:

```
@Entity("rules")
public class Rule {
  public String urlRule; // regular expression
}
```

I then have a unit test:

```
@Test
public void testRule() {
  Rule r = Rule.findById(ID);
  assertNotNull(r);

  final String urlToTest = "/foo/bar?q=1";
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(r.urlRule);
  assertTrue(pattern.matcher(urlToTest).matches());
}
```

Now, i know for the example URL i have that the string does match, but the above test fails.

I can make it pass if i just change the test by:

```
String regex = "\\/foo\\/bar\\?q=(.*)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
```

so i just essentially hardcode the regular expression, it passes, but if i use the value i saved in the database, the regular expression never works.

Obviously i can't hardcode the regular expression in a variable, i have to store it in the database. Is there something I'm missing with respect to data type i'm storing the regular expression as?

I have a feeling i'm just missing something obvious and i've been staring at this for too long. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After chasing this down a bit more, and i should have looked here further, Morphia was saving the regular expression by escaping the escaped string so what was stored wasn't correct.